# Set window to open up on a specific monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, tv

I am using Windows 10. I have a dual setup with a monitor and a TV. I use the TV only when I watch movies, sports, etc. Otherwise I keep it turned off. When I press a window sometimes it opens up in the TV instead of my monitor and makes me turn on and off the TV several times a day. Is there any way we can set the pages to open up in the monitor with the pointer or something similar to that? In Linux we are able to do it with compizconfig, but I couldn't find a way to do it in Windows 10.

Comment: Isn't Win+left or Win+right move that window to active/monitor screen?

Comment: Yeap it does. Wouldn't it be nice if i were to find a setting to make them open up on the current screen with the pointer? Damn i wish the Nvidia drivers for Linux would be a lot better, i can't use my GPU with Linux :( stuck with windows.